# Spring data jpa : One to one Relationship

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I have Sensor Entity has Relationship to Location Entity

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TemperatureSensor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private float temperature;
    private float min;
    private float max;
    private float timeInterval;
    private boolean activityState;
    @OneToOne
    private Location location;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Long coordinates;
    private String name;
    private EnvironmentState environmentState = EnvironmentState.NORMAL_CASE;
    @OneToOne
    private TemperatureSensor temperatureSensor;
}
```

I created two endpoints to initiate each entity, so I send Sensor object using Postman like this and get location_id null in the database.
The same is happening with Location.

```
    {
    "temperature" : "15.2",
    "min" :"9.0",
    "max" : "20.0", 
    "timeInterval" : "552.5", 
    "activityState" : "true",
    "location_id" :"1"
    }
```

Also, I tried to send location object and I got the exception: **object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing**

```
{
    "temperature" : "15.2",
    "min" :"9.0",
    "max" : "20.0", 
    "timeInterval" : "552.5", 
    "activityState" : "true",
    "location" :{"coordinates": "123","name" : "loc01"}
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that you are missing cascade options on your `@OneToOne` annotations. Try using `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` instead (this will cascade all operations PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, DETACH to the other entity).

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TemperatureSensor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private float temperature;
    private float min;
    private float max;
    private float timeInterval;
    private boolean activityState;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Location location;
}
```

```java
Entity
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Long coordinates;
    private String name;
    private EnvironmentState environmentState = EnvironmentState.NORMAL_CASE;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TemperatureSensor temperatureSensor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!
but I still need to pass the whole object.
how can I pass only the foreign key

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to have that automated. If the given `location_id` already exists, then you need to actively retrieve it from the database and set it to the received `TemperatureSensor`. Unless you want to have a custom persist query for your `TemperatureSensor` but I am not sure that is the best option.